# Desglosar informacion de archivo .txt para guarda en base de datos

Tags: php, html

function filedata(){
    $file = fopen('data_centrales/datos_AVC05.log', 'r');
    if(!$file){
        echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    } else {
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
            yield $line;
        }
    }
}

$coincidencias = array();
$data = array();

foreach(fileData() as $line){

```
if(preg_match('#^(?P<tipo>\w+)\/(?P<categoria>\w+)\s+(?P<rest>.+)#', $line, $coincidencias) === 1){

    $parts = explode(' ',preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $coincidencias['rest']));

    $data[] = [
        'id' => $parts[2],
        'fecha' => $parts[3],
        'hora' => $parts[4],
        'categoria' => $coincidencias['categoria'],
        'tipo' => $coincidencias['tipo']
    ];

        $datoss = "insert into ".$parts[2]." ".$parts[3]." ".$parts[4]." ".$coincidencias['categoria']." ".$coincidencias['tipo']." ";

} else {

    $data[count($data)-1]['descripcion'] .= $line;
    $line1 .=$line;
}
```

}
echo $line1;
//print_r($data);
echo $datoss;

Salida de datos

```
-->DIGITAL PATH QUALITY SUPERVISION
-->
-->
-->
-->ES
-->
-->DIP      DIPPART  ESL2   QSV    SECTION  DATE    TIME
-->
-->36GAMGS           26     54     0        181025  101510

insert into 628 181025 1101 APT O1 Array
(
    [id] => 628
    [fecha] => 181025
    [hora] => 1101
    [categoria] => APT
    [tipo] => O1
)
```

quiero hacer esto basicamente:

```
insert into 628 181025 1101 APT O1 Array
(
    [id] => 628
    [fecha] => 181025
    [hora] => 1101
    [categoria] => APT
    [tipo] =>"PATH QUALITY SUPERVISION -ES DIP      DIPPART  ESL2   QSV    SECTION  DATE    TIME - 36GAMGS           26     54     0        181025  101510"

)
```

Comment: Intentaste algo? hay que escribir un lindo proceso que vaya linea por linea, y extraiga los datos que te sirvan en cada paso

Comment: @gbianchi no he tratado nada aún, sé sobre las funciones substr y strpos que podrian ayudarme pero no sé como, AYUDA!

Comment: Creo que deberías intentar recorrer la información del txt linea por linea. para extraer la  información.Te dejo un link   que te puede ser de ayuda http://biolucas.com/como-leer-un-archivo-txt-linea-a-linea-en-php-fget/

Answer (score 0):

Intenta probar lo siguiente para que obtengas un array donde esten todos los datos que quieres ingresar en tu tabla, ya despues lo que te quedaria seria recorrer el arreglo `data` e ir llamando a tu `insert`

```
<?php 
$fileData = function(){
    $file = fopen('formato.txt', 'r');
    if(!$file){
        echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    } else {
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
            yield $line;
        }
    }
};
$coincidencias = [];
$data = [];
foreach($fileData() as $line){
    if(preg_match('#^(?P<tipo>\w+)\/(?P<categoria>\w+)\s+(?P<rest>.+)#', $line, $coincidencias) === 1){
        $parts = explode(' ',preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $coincidencias['rest']));
        $data[] = [
            'id' => $parts[2],
            'fecha' => $parts[3],
            'hora' => $parts[4],
            'categoria' => $coincidencias['categoria'],
            'tipo' => $coincidencias['tipo'],
            'descripcion' => ''
        ];
    } else {
        $data[count($data)-1]['descripcion'] .= $line;
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /var/www/html/saraweb/prueba.php on line 13

qué puede ser?

Comment: Cambia $coincidencias = []; y $data = []; por $coincidencias = array(); y $data = array();

Comment: De todas formas dime ke version de php estas usando???

Comment: PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2018 10:56:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo de uso de generators que es lo que empleo para leer linea por linea en este caso es enm php 5.5, recuerda cambiar lo que te puse en el comentario anterior. Esta e sla url: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/05/how-to-use-yield-keyword-php/

Comment: Me podrías ayudar, no entiendo tu manera de acomodar el `script` para realizar la función, como podría acomodarlo correctamente

Comment: si haces el cambio de en vez de inicializar los arreglos con $variable = []; por $variable = array(), te sigue dando el mismo error????

Comment: Respondi como una respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
function filedata(){
    $file = fopen('data_centrales/datos_AVC05.log', 'r');
    if(!$file){
        echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    } else {
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
            yield $line;
        }
    }
}


$coincidencias = array();
$data = array();

foreach(fileData() as $line){

    if(preg_match('#^(?P<tipo>\w+)\/(?P<categoria>\w+)\s+(?P<rest>.+)#', $line, $coincidencias) === 1){

        $parts = explode(' ',preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $coincidencias['rest']));

        $data[] = [
            'id' => $parts[2],
            'fecha' => $parts[3],
            'hora' => $parts[4],
            'categoria' => $coincidencias['categoria'],
            'tipo' => $coincidencias['tipo']
        ];

            $datoss = "insert into ".$parts[2]." ".$parts[3]." ".$parts[4]." ".$coincidencias['categoria']." ".$coincidencias['tipo']." ";

    } else {

        $data[count($data)-1]['descripcion'] .= $line;
        $line1 .=$line;
    }

}
echo $line1;
//print_r($data);
echo $datoss;
```

Estoy usándolo de esta manera, pero lo que sucede es que la descripción debo concatenar debo hacer que este en toda una linea, y no sé  como llamarle para después si la puede concatenar junto al Insert y Más, debo ponerle una condicional a la varible `$line1` para que cuando sea otro dato, mande la consulta y después siga con el siguiente dato

Comment: Y como te sale la descripción????

Comment: lo agregare en un nueva respuesta, gracias

Comment: No pongas las aclaraciones como respuestas, edita tu pregunta original y añadelo

Comment: vale :v ya listo